How to Manage Update Authority in Metaplex Core Collection to Allow NFT Creation Only Through My Program?
I'm developing a game and have created a Metaplex Core collection. The update authority for the collection is set to the wallet address I created. My goal is to allow NFTs to be added to this collection only through my program. I want to prevent any external party from adding NFTs to the collection by simply using the collection key.
I tried adding my program address as an Update Plugin, but this approach didn't work as expected. I want to ensure that NFTs can only be added when the update authority is managed by my program.
How can I achieve this? Is there a specific configuration or a different method I should use to enforce this control?
Thank you for your assistance!

Programs themselves cannot sign directly and therefore can't be used as the Update Authority of a collection. Instead they do this through PDAs. I would recommend reading up on how (PDAs work and then set the Update Authority of the collection to a PDA signer of your program.
